# How to make client side validation when loading Partial View in my page using jquery in Mvc2

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I am returning partial view

```
public virtual PartialViewResult Create()
{
    return PartialView("Create");
}
```

and loading the view in my page when clicking create button with jquery

```
function createVendor() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Vendor/create',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#popup").html(result).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
}
```

in my class I am using DataAnnotations for validation, making reference for js files and add adding

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

before begin form.

the problem is that when I click save the first time with wrong data the validation not working but it is working the second time I click save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear all I found the answer here thanks for you :

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/11/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the `EnableClientValidation()` is that it examines the model and injects html wherever it needs to go.  So you may need to call `EnableClientValidation()` again in your partial view you return.

Comment: I already added it to my partial view and to my page that I am loading the partial view in and the validation still working the second time only.

Answer (score 0):

[This blogpost](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx) is a great resource if you're using the jQuery validation plugin. I know the question isn't asking about the plugin specifically but seeing as I arrived here while searching for help with it, I thought this might help someone else.